Server appearing offline to browser, even though it is online
I have launched 8 or 9 webservers, personally, and something is very unusual this time regarding http/https transfer with apache2. Ports 80 and 443 are up, as indicated by nmap on a remote client machine:
nmap -Pn -p 80 xx.xx.xx.xx
Starting Nmap x.xx ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-12-05 22:31 CST
Nmap scan report for xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx)
Host is up (0.019s latency).

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp filtered http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.09 seconds

I'm listening on port 80, as confirmed by netstat on the server. If I omit
-Pn,

which according to the man page will
"Treat all hosts as online -- skip host discovery,"

I receive the following feedback:
nmap -p 80 xx.xx.xx.xx
Starting Nmap x.xx ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-12-05 22:31 CST
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 2.16 seconds

Why does it not ping with nmap, unless I force it with the -Pn option? I haven't been able to get any browser to pull up the default apache page that is standard procedure when you first launch a webserver, either, for some reason.
I should mention, perhaps, that I had a cyber attack two weeks ago that went straight for the bios, and I have had to beef up security in a number of different ways since then. Edit: I had this particular configuration running in an identical manner though two weeks ago.

The port is filtered, which means the server is not returning TCP requests on that port. This usually indicates that a firewall is blocking the requests.

You're not forcing ping with -Pn. You're telling nmap not to ping, and test ports directly. Furthermore, filtered doesn't mean online?

I'm testing an entirely different transfer protocol than just ping. Further, firewalls block requests completely, in my experience. I appreciate the comments, but I answered the question myself below, because apparently, stack exchange wanted to remove my user name from the question. It has returned since then, but this entire experience has been a little ridiculous.

Sometimes, even though a port is open on your firewall, it is not listening. A tool such as netcat can force a port to listen. For example,
nc -lp 443

will listen (-l) on port 443 with tcp protocol (-p), the port used for https.
